# Resolve/Close issue in JIRA using PHP

Tags: php, soap, jira

Any one has idea on how to resolve close issue in Jira using PHP? I tried doing update it didnt help. Then i tried progressworkflow action and it throws error when i send resolution as array. Here is sample code :

```
$rIssue= array();
$rIssue['resolution']  = 1;
$result = $soap->progressWorkflowAction($auth,$issue,$rIssue);
```

Here is error :

```
com.atlassian.jira.rpc.exception.RemoteException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Array"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:449)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.service.IssueServiceImpl.getWorkflowTransitionUtil(IssueServiceImpl.java:951)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.service.IssueServiceImpl.progressWorkflowAction(IssueServiceImpl.java:737)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.service.IssueServiceImpl.progressWorkflowAction(IssueServiceImpl.java:711)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.JiraSoapServiceImpl.progressWorkflowAction(JiraSoapServiceImpl.java:314)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:453)
    at com.atlassian.jira.soap.axis.JiraAxisSoapService.invoke(JiraAxisSoapService.java:44)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.servlet.rpc.LazyAxisDecoratorServlet.service(LazyAxisDecoratorServlet.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraLastFilter.doFilter(JiraLastFilter.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.HeaderSanitisingFilter.doFilter(HeaderSanitisingFilter.java:44)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.accesslog.AccessLogFilter.executeRequest(AccessLogFilter.java:102)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.accesslog.AccessLogFilter.doFilter(AccessLogFilter.java:86)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.jira.security.xsrf.XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.doFilter(XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.security.auth.trustedapps.filter.TrustedApplicationsFilter.doFilter(TrustedApplicationsFilter.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.BaseLoginFilter.doFilter(BaseLoginFilter.java:142)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraLoginFilter.doFilter(JiraLoginFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
    at com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider.internal.servlet.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:69)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.util.profiling.filters.ProfilingFilter.doFilter(ProfilingFilter.java:99)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JIRAProfilingFilter.doFilter(JIRAProfilingFilter.java:16)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.ActionCleanupDelayFilter.doFilter(ActionCleanupDelayFilter.java:59)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.RequestCleanupFilter.doFilter(RequestCleanupFilter.java:53)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.johnson.filters.AbstractJohnsonFilter.doFilter(AbstractJohnsonFilter.java:72)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilterInternal(GzipFilter.java:81)
    at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.cache.AbstractCachingFilter.doFilter(AbstractCachingFilter.java:33)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.encoding.AbstractEncodingFilter.doFilter(AbstractEncodingFilter.java:41)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.PathMatchingEncodingFilter.doFilter(PathMatchingEncodingFilter.java:49)
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:31)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.jira.startup.JiraStartupChecklistFilter.doFilter(JiraStartupChecklistFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraFirstFilter.doFilter(JiraFirstFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:199)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:282)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:767)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:697)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:889)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Any idea? How this can be fixed? Or is there any other way to close ticket?

Comment: Just FYI: `$rIssue` get's casted to *string* and then is `"Array"`. Obviously not what you aimed for.

Comment: but that function expects array of field and values for those fields to set. Any suggestion you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a parameter.  The argument signature for progressWorkflowAction() is:

```
progressWorkflowAction(String token, String key, String actionID, RemoteFieldValuesArray[])
```

So you should probably have somethign like this:

```
$result = $soap->progressWorkflowAction($auth, $issue, "resolve", $rIssue);
```

You can use

```
getAvailableActions(String token, String issueKey)
```

to determine what the appropriate values are for that third argument.

Comment: Sometimes you miss small things that u never notice how many times you read code :p. Good catch, but to correct for third parameter you pass resolution number not name. So it was . `$result = $soap->progressWorkflowAction($auth, $issue, 21, $rIssue);`

Comment: Cool, thanks. I wasn't sure if it was a name or number. Sometimes both work in JIRA, so I just took a shot. Glad it's working out.